# Are there free webservices that I can use to fetch data in combination with Core Location

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am new to GPS.If i send  "hotels" in label , any free webservice is available to see them as map?any tutorial please? is there any free webservice to give location name if i give current latitude & longitude values?

Comment: What have you found so far with Google?

Comment: google will give image only..i need dynamic map through map kit.is it possible?

Comment: That's not what Chris meant. What have you found on google while searching for things related to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your questions one by one :

*is there any free webservice to give location name if i give current latitude & longitude values?*

This is called reverse geocoding and it's in the SDK already - check out [the docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoder_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

*any free webservice available to see them as a map*

A quick google search for 'hotels api' found a few results for hotels data feeds [like this one](http://www.cleartrip.com/api/docs/hotel-api/#Search).

You will also need to read the [documentation for MKMapView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) - there are a few sample apps linked from that page that it's worth downloading and seeing how they work.

*any tutorial please*

Google for it - a quick search for 'map kit tutorial' returns [this as the first link](http://iphonebcit.wordpress.com/iphone-map-kit-tutorial/).

---

PS One of the best ways to get your question ignored is to ask more than one thing at once - you've asked three questions here and seem to have made no effort to find out the answers yourself first - people generally don't like that (take a look at the comments if you don't believe me!)

If you have more than one question, ask them separately here on stack overflow and give some examples of things that you have tried already :)